# Smarty Templates not working Properly with Internet Explorer

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, smarty3

I have used Smarty Templates with Codeigniter. Everything is working fine with some issues thou but those are very different..

The point is site works fine if opened in firefox and google chrome.

But problem is if i open the site in Internet Explorer, Most of the Website Stuff Don't work.

Like the Menus in my Website when opened in firefox generates this ouput.

```
<ul class="collapse" id="menu">
<li class="nav-header">Menu</li>
    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li>
                            <a href="http://localhost/projects/HouseRentSystem/admin/dashboard/System">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                                </li>
              <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span class="link-title">Residentials</span>
                <span class="fa arrow"></span>
            </a>
                                    <ul class="collapse">
                                                                        <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/projects/HouseRentSystem/admin/residentials/Houses">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Houses
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                                            <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/projects/HouseRentSystem/admin/residentials/Flats">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Flats
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                </ul>
                    </li>
              <li class="active">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span class="link-title">Configuration</span>
                <span class="fa arrow"></span>
            </a>
                                    <ul class="collapse in">
                                                                        <li class="active">
                        <a href="http://localhost/projects/HouseRentSystem/admin/configurations/SitePreferences">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Site Settings
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                                            <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/projects/HouseRentSystem/admin/configurations/ManageTabs">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Manage Tabs
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                                            <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/projects/HouseRentSystem/admin/configurations/ManageForms">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Manage Forms
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                </ul>
                    </li>
    </ul>
```

but when i open in IE. it dont generate the code which i coded in smarty and i get this HTML output.

```
<ul class="collapse" id="menu">
<li class="nav-header">Menu</li>
    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
    </ul>
```

anything coded inside it like `foreach`, its like it never executed. How is that possible. i thought programming is a server side language. how come a browser effect the programming language.

Here is the Code if someone can point out where i have gone wrong that it should work in firefox and chrome but not the IE.

```
{{$var = ksort($Menu)}}
<ul id="menu" class="collapse">
<li class="nav-header">Menu</li>
    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
    {{foreach $Menu as $MainMenu}}
  {{$FormCIPath = explode("/", $MainMenu['FormCIPath'])}}
        <li {{checkActiveClassMainMenu($FormCIPath[1])}}>
            {{if isset($MainMenu['SubMenu'])}}
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span class="link-title">{{$MainMenu['Name']}}</span>
                <span class="fa arrow"></span>
            </a>
            {{else}}
                <a href="{{url}}{{$MainMenu['FormCIPath']}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> {{$MainMenu['Name']}}</a>
            {{/if}}
            {{if isset($MainMenu['SubMenu'])}}
            <ul>
                {{$var = ksort($MainMenu['SubMenu'])}}
                {{foreach $MainMenu['SubMenu'] as $SubMenu}}
                    {{$FormCIPath = explode("/", $SubMenu['SubFormCIPath'])}}
                    <li {{checkActiveClassSubMenu($FormCIPath[2])}}>
                        <a href="{{url}}{{$SubMenu['SubFormCIPath']}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> {{$SubMenu['SubName']}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {{/foreach}}
            </ul>
            {{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/foreach}}
</ul><!-- /#menu -->
```

---

Update: Thanks to Marcin Nabiałek Answer, I figured out where is the problem, but i am not sure why it is giving the problem?

i did var_dump inside the inner foreach loop, seems like IE dont want to go inside the foreach loop, cuz IE dont return anything. IE dont even see the foreach loop, no matter what i write inside it, HTML PHP it will never render the data>>

i added this line

```
<pre>Test - {{$menus|@var_dump}}</pre>
```

inside the nested foreach loop. the main foreach loops run fines but the inner foreach, seems like IE dont wanna read it.

Only Firefox and Chrome Reads it. i dont have other browswers installed or i would have checked on them too.

Comment: what is javascript:;

Comment: @dcc
There is no javascript except the the js of bootstrap..

Comment: "ie don't want to go inside the foreach"? IE is a browser. Smarty is running on the server. The browser has nothing to do with a foreach not being executed, unless you've written some `if(browser == ie) { don't do this }`

Comment: xD, i know but why it is doing that, you can see the code.
var_dump the variable works for 1 browser, but dont on the other,
Even if i write HTMl tags inside that other foreach loop, it will not show on page of IE, but will show on chrome and firefox.
Seems like a strange Problem..

Answer (score 0):

Smarty has nothing in common with differences with displaying data in different browser. It's the same as PHP (Smarty is PHP library) so it's definitely not Smarty fault.

But it's quite possible some part of your code rely on for example User Agent or your browser settings.

You should first add after this line:

```
{{$var = ksort($Menu)}}
```

the following line:

```
{{$Menu|@var_dump}}
```

to make sure the same data is in both browsers. Probably it's not so you should investigate code that generates `$Menu` content and make sure it's not browser dependent.

Comment: IE Shows `NULL`, where as if opened in firefox or Internet Explorer it shows an `Array`.

Comment: Thanks to ur var_dump, i think the problem is here in second foreach loop
`{{foreach $menus as $key => $subrow}}`.cuz after this foreach loop line i used this line
`{{$subrow|@var_dump}}` and it didnt return any value in IE not even the NULL, just Nothing Blank.

Comment: @SizzlingCode As you see, result of `var_dump` is different in both browser so it means that it's created using some browser specific configuration.You need to investigate how `$Menu` is created because now it seems not related to Smarty at all. It's rather how it's created in PHP

Comment: What Should i do? cuz this is not the error, and as far as i know, Nested Foreach loops are allowed by PHP.
I dont know how to fix it O_o?

Comment: @SizzlingCode You should not have put this `var_dump` inside loop but just at the beginning of that Smarty file to make sure the same content is set for `$Menu` variable in Smarty for all browsers.

Comment: Yes, but i already had checked it on your request, and IE was not giving result as the rest of the two browsers, so i wanted to find out if thee is issue in array creation, and turns out i was right.
may be nested foreach dont work in IE, or i guess my IE is faulty.. 
cuz i cant find any other sane explanation to this problem.